# Spacing around equal sign with breqn

Tags: spacing, math-operators, breqn

In the following minimal example, the spacing around the equal sign is wrong. How can I fix this? It is rendered as `x  =0` instead of `x = 0`. Changing to `align*` instead of `dmath*` works fine.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}
   \begin{dmath*}
     \sum_{x=0}^{n}
   \end{dmath*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Incorrect spacing]

Comment: Simple: don't use `breqn`. This is just one of the bugs in it.

Comment: I wish. My input is automatically generated by another tool, so it's hard to know where to break lines.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in `breqn`, which I always recommend not using.

Workaround: use `\hiderel` whenever `breqn` has different ideas from the usual typesetting rules. You need to do similarly for every relation symbol you want in places like that.

Note that `amsmath` is not required, but recommended anyway.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}           

\begin{dmath*}
\sum_{x\hiderel{=}0}^{n}
\end{dmath*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, that slightly defeats the promise of automation :/ I'm using breqn to automatically get decent-looking formulas (I don't have much control over the input), so it's not obvious whether I can do this.

Comment: If the code is always generated by some programme, then perhaps you could write a preprocessor to massage the latex code  a bit before texing it

Comment: @Clément In my experience, `breqn` is very far from producing decent looking formulas.

Comment: @daleif: Indeed, but writing code to break formulas properly is going to be tricky; I have no reasons to think I'll do better that the authors of `breqn`.

Comment: The preprocessor should fix things like limits etc and the leave the rest. There are some rules behind what breqn does, and it might be possible to write a preprocessor that understands some of it and thus reducing the needed manual intervention needed for example for a long align. I don't see breqn getting fixed any time soon, unless someone puts up the money for someone to take a really close look at it.