# using breqn error

Tags: errors, line-breaking, compilation-error

getting a Argument of \math@egroup has an extra }  error that disappears as soon as I comment out the breqn 3 lines

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{subcaption}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext,amsthm}
%\usepackage[ backend=biber,
%style=alphabetic,
%sorting=ynt
%]{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{main.bib}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[mathpazo]{flexisym}  %required by breqn
\usepackage{breqn}   % auto next lines equations running off page

% \usepackage{mathpazo}
% \usepackage[mathpazo]{flexisym}  %required by breqn
% \usepackage{breqn} 
\begin{document}

$ y \in \mathbb{R}^ \mathcal{C}  $ 

\end{document}
```

Also `breqn` doesn't seem to auto next line properly should I try a different package?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[mathpazo]{flexisym}  %required by breqn
\usepackage{breqn} 

\begin{document}
Consider the following list $a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,$   
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: breqn isn't really recommended, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/483852/2388 or 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/288236/2388

Comment: uh so use what then???

Comment: Did the provided answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that `breqn` can help in that case. Here's working code.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mlist}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \thinmuskip=3mu plus 3mu
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { , } { #1 }
  $\seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { ,\allowbreak }$
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Consider the following list \mlist{a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
  22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,
  3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
  2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,
  67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
  2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,
  5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
  2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,
  5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
  2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,
  5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,
  2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,
  4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,
  2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,
  3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,
  2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,
  3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,
  2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,
  3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,
  2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,
  3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,
  2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,
  3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,
  2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,
  2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,
  2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,
  1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,
  2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,
  a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,
  2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,
  2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,
  2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,
  2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,
  2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,
  2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,
  2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
  22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,
  3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
  2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,a,1,2,3,4,5,
  67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,,a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
  2,2,2,22,2,2,2, a,1,2,3,4,5,67,3,2,2,2,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,22,2,2,2,}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to automatically remove empty entries:

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mlist}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \thinmuskip=3mu plus 3mu
  \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { #1 }
  $\clist_use:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { ,\allowbreak }$
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Compare the first lines:

[image]

Comment: actually I just wanted  to have an like auto don't run off page thing which I thought was breqn  
what does your code do?

Comment: @HaoSun `breqn` does automatic splitting of *displays*, inside the specialized environments it defines.